# Multiple choice application

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath =     
    @"C:\Users\User\Documents\flower.txt";
    List<string> lines =     
    File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
    int count = lines.Count();

    Random rnd = new Random();
    //label1.Text = rnd.Next().ToString();
    QuestionsWithAnswer qtn = new.     
    QuestionsWithAnswer();
    string[] line = lines[count - 1].Split(',');

    lblQuestion.Text = qtn.question1 = line[0];
    radOpt1.Text = qtn.opt1 = line[1];
    radOpt2.Text = qtn.opt2 = line[2];
    radOpt3.Text = qtn.opt3 = line[3];
    radOpt4.Text = qtn.opt4 = line[4];
    radOpt5.Text = qtn.opt5 = line[5];

    radOpt4.Checked = true;

    label1.Text = rnd.Next(count).ToString();
}
```

I am developing a multiple choice application. This app reads from a text file for its question and options. I want the questions to be generated randomly. The code is working but it's bring same question whenever I load the app the first time even with my random class.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. For example, what is `new.` supposed to be?

Comment: Why aren't you using `rnd` to select the question?

Comment: `line[0]` will always be the first line from the file. What do you expect it to do? Can you share the portion of file which has question and answers?

Comment: instead of new Random() try seeding it with a value. ie: new Random( Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()); But it is not clear where you are using the Random(). An easy way would be ordering the lines by Guid.NewGuid().

Answer (score 0):

Probably you meant ordering the questions randomly. An easy way would be:

```
List<string> lines = File
                       .ReadAllLines(filePath)
                       .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

Note: Why wouldn't you use a database instead of a text file.

Comment: Trying to avoid having heavy app

Comment: @OfodileJustCodeChukwubuikem, What does "heavy" mean I don't understand.

Comment: Taking about the size of the app... I just want it simple

Comment: It IS simple. It is easier then trying to work with a text file.

Comment: But texfile is also part of the requirement

Comment: OK I think you are doing some kind of weird homework.